# Icons with actions inside of buttons

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, twitter-bootstrap

I'm using RoR 3.1 and Twitter Bootstrap, and want to create a button that links to a controller action-- the caveat being that **inside** of that button, I'd like to add a 'icon-remove' link that, when clicked, will delete the containing button.

Is this possible?

My working button:

```
<%= link_to exp, edit_exp_path, :class => "btn btn-inverse", :controller => :exps, :method => :edit %>
```

My working 'delete' icon:

```
<%= link_to "", exp_path(exp.id), :class => "icon-remove", :confirm => "Are you sure?", :controller => :exps, :method => :delete  %>
```

How do I put my delete icon inside of the button?

Edit: To be clear, I want to retain both actions with the button.  Clicking on button text should link to 'edit' controller action, while clicking the 'x' provided by Bootstrap's 'icon-remove' class should delete the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use a button group: http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/components.html#buttonGroups

The button on the left would be your normal button, and on the right, you can have your `X`.

It would make more sense to users I think, and would minimize the number of misclicks.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, Robin.  I'll look into this route.

Answer (score 0):

Put your class in the text of the link instead:

`<%= link_to "<span class='btn btn-inverse'>#{exp}</span>".html_safe, edit_exp_path, :controller => :exps, :method => :edit %>`

`<%= link_to "<i class='icon-remove'></i>".html_safe, exp_path(exp.id), :confirm => "Are you sure?", :controller => :exps, :method => :delete  %>`

Use html_safe to properly display the content.

Edited: Added example to first link for editing the `exp`

Here is an example with my own code:

`<%= link_to "<span class='btn btn-inverse'>Test Data</span>".html_safe, "#" %>`

It displays the button:

[image]

Comment: Maybe I need to be more clear:  I want the button to retain both actions.  If you click the link text, it takes you to the edit action.  If you click the 'X' provided by the 'icon-remove class', it should delete the button. Does this make sense?

Comment: That does make sense. However, I wonder if it will make sense to your clients. That would be very confusing that the same button performs two different actions.

Comment: I think you're right about confusion, as Robin above pointed out as well.  I'll try the button groups.  Thanks, Kobaltz